# What does these words meaning in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this passage from an article. There are words being bold below :

> The Internet of Things (IoT) will breakthrough in three directions:
>   **boundary, dimension, and scenario**.
>
> With the development of 5G and edge computing, computing power will
>   not be limited to cloud computing centers, expanding to everything and
>   building a distributed computing platform. At the same time, the
>   insight into time and space, the two most important dimensions of the
>   physical world, will become the basic capabilities of the
>   new-generation IoT platforms. This will promote the integration of IoT
>   with more scenarios such as energy, power, industry, logistics,
>   medical treatment, and intelligent city, and create greater value.

What do they meaning in this sentence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence introduces the three topics of the writer's next paragraph.

The writer imagines a [boundary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/boundary), an imaginary line or limit, which will no longer confine computing power to cloud computing centers. The [dimension](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dimension)s he/she refers to later are those of time and space: "the two most important dimensions of the physical world". By [scenario](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/scenario.html) it becomes clear he/she means such things as "energy, power, industry, logistics, medical treatment, and intelligent city".

Comment: Wow, it is more complicated that I have though. Thanks ^_^